# Multiple select with different array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, algorithm, data-structures

I want that when a value is input into my  multiselect it push each value of the multi select into a different array and the default value of the multi array is empty so let say the first multiple is 1 and 2  ans second is 2 and 3it push into an array and create something like this {1:[1,2],2:[2,3]}
here is my code below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchApprovalItemType, fetchAllStaff } from './data';

import Set from './set';
import MultiSelect from './MultiSelect';

const AddApprovalItems = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [staffs, setStaff] = useState([]);
  const [approvalItemLevel, setApprovalItemLevel] = useState('');
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState({});
  const [sets, setSets] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const item = await fetchApprovalItemType();
      setItems(item);
    };

    const fetchStaff = async () => {
      const staff = await fetchAllStaff();
      setStaff(staff);
    };

    fetchData();
    fetchStaff();
  }, []);

  const handleApprovalLevelChange = (e) => {
    const level = parseInt(e.target.value);
    setApprovalItemLevel(level);

    // Create sets based on the entered level
    const newSets = Array.from({ length: level }, (_, index) => index + 1);
    setSets(newSets);

    // Reset selected options for the new approval level
    setSelectedOptions((prevOptions) => ({
      ...prevOptions,
      [level]: [],
    }));
  };

  const handleMultiSelectChange = (selected, index) => {
    setSelectedOptions((prevOptions) => ({
      ...prevOptions,
      [approvalItemLevel]: {
        ...prevOptions[approvalItemLevel],
        [index]: selected.map(option => option.value),
      },
    }));
    console.log(selectedOptions)
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(selectedOptions)
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center lg:mt-[5%] mt-[20%]">
      <div className="card lg:w-1/2 w-[80%] rounded-[10px]">
        <div className="p-6">
          <div className="flex">
            <h4 className="mb-5 uppercase dark:text-gray-300">Add Home Ownership</h4>
          </div>

          <form className="px-10">
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label className="block mb-2 font-semibold" htmlFor="approvalItemLevel">
                Approval Item Type
              </label>
              <div>
                <select
                  id="approvalItemLevel"
                  className="form-select form-select-sm"
                  onChange={handleApprovalLevelChange}
                  value={approvalItemLevel}
                >
                  <option value="">Select Approval Item Level</option>
                  {items.map((it, idx) => (
                    <option key={idx} value={it}>{it}</option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label className="block mb-2 font-semibold" htmlFor="approvalItemType">
                Approval Item level
              </label>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  id="approvalItemType"
                  name="approvalItemType"
                  className="form-input w-full placeholder:text-gray-400"
                  onChange={handleApprovalLevelChange}
                  value={approvalItemLevel}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            
            {/* Display the created sets */}
            <div className="mb-3">
              {sets.map((setNumber, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  <Set />
                  <MultiSelect 
                    option={staffs.map((staff) => ({
                      label: staff.email,
                      value: staff.id,
                    }))}
                    // value={selectedOptions[approvalItemLevel]?.[setNumber] || []}
                    // onChange={(selected) => handleMultiSelectChange(selected, setNumber)}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="btn bg-primary/90 text-white hover:bg-primary" onClick={onSubmit}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddApprovalItems;
```

I tried the my solution but I can multiple select and don't know what the problem is

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? How have you attempted to debug this?

Comment: Hello, could you give us the current output of your solution ? So we can evaluate how it differs from the expected result.

Comment: I would start by adding lots of `console.log` statements. Are you getting the expected functions called at the expected time with the expected data? Is the intermediate result always what you think it should be?